# How can i remove the Button hover color in Mui?

Tags: reactjs, linux, button, material-ui, hover

I need to disable the hover color but seems like its not working !

```
const ButtonWrapper = styled(Box)`
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 3% 0 auto;
  & > button,
  & > p,
  & > div {
    margin-right: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
`;

const LoginButton = styled(Button)` 
  color: #2874f0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  box-shadow:none;
  border:1px solid #DBDBDB;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
  text-transform:none;
  font-weight:500;
  height:32px;
  width:130px;
`;


const CustomButtons = () => {
  return (
    <ButtonWrapper>
      <LoginButton variant="contained">Login</LoginButton>
    </ButtonWrapper>
  );
};

export default CustomButtons;
```

There is a blue hover effect coming that i dont want; I tried the inline style sx={{ "&:hover": { backgroundColor: "transparent" }} } but its not working.

How can i add the transparent style to the LoginButton using the &:hover?

i written like

```
const LoginButton = styled(Button)` 
  color: #2874f0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  box-shadow:none;
  border:1px solid #DBDBDB;
  padding:5px 40px 5px 40px;
  text-transform:none;
  font-weight:500;
  height:32px;
  width:130px;

//dont know the correct syntax
   "&:hover": {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
`;
//its not working
```

Comment: Your `padding` has a double `:`

Comment: thanks but how that make sense with button hover?

Comment: Try to set the same background color on hover. 
You are using MUI 5 with styled engine?

Comment: yes it worked i set the bgcolor to white and solved the issue ,using MUI 5

Answer (score 1):

It is the `MuiButton-root` class which is not letting you change the background color. You can target this class using **`sx`** prop or `styled`. Check the fix below, I'm using `sx` prop and targeting `MuiButton-root` class and setting the background to transparent.

```
<LoginButton variant="contained" sx={{ '&.MuiButton-root:hover':{bgcolor: 'transparent'} }}>
    Login
  </LoginButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue , I solved my issue with this command ,sx={{ "&.MuiButtonBase-root:hover": { backgroundColor: "white" } }}